# Separate sencha application from backend java server for better work enviroment

Tags: javascript, java, extjs, jetty, sencha-cmd

I have an ext.js as a frontend and java as a backend and my main page is index.jsp. I want to run my frontend separate from backend using sencha app watch, what is the correct process? I have configured web.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app`enter code here
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  metadata-complete="true"
  version="2.5"
>
  <!-- ==================================================================== -->
  <!-- Reverse HTTP Proxy for the Sencha Cmd web server, e.g.               -->
  <!-- http://localhost:1841/backend/test.php will reflect                  -->
  <!-- http://example.com/backend/test.php                                  -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>transparentReverseProxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.ProxyServlet$Transparent</servlet-class>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ProxyTo</param-name>
        <param-value>https://0.0.0.0:5001/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>HostHeader</param-name>
        <param-value>index.jsp#gateway</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/backend</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>transparentReverseProxy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/backend/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <!-- <welcome-file>test.html</welcome-file> -->
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>`
```

but it's showing me an error Problem accessing /index.jsp. Reason:JSP support not configured.